# Verificar se dicionário é nulo ou está vazio?

Tags: dicionário, typescript

Em um retorno de um método tenho um dicionário resultante, ás vezes ele pode vir vazio, daí estou com problema de identificar quando ele está vazio ou não.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= this.last; i++)
{
    this.select(i, (item) => 
    {
        console.debug(JSON.stringify(item));
        if(item != null)
            all.push(item);
    });
}
```

A saída do debug é a seguinte:

```
database.ts:104 {"id":"1","descricao":"Alimentação"}
database.ts:104 {"id":"2","descricao":"Transporte"}
database.ts:104 {"id":"3","descricao":"Saúde"}
database.ts:104 {"id":"4","descricao":"Educação"}
database.ts:104 {}
database.ts:104 {}
database.ts:104 {"id":"7","descricao":"Mais uma conta"}
```

Eu quero executar o `all.push(item)` apenas quando item não está `vazio`, tentei usar o `.length` mas não funciona, coloquei `console.log(item.length)` e em todos caso retorna `undefined`. Como posso verificar se é vazio?

Comment: Defina vazio. Sem maiores informações não se sei se dá para responder isso.

Comment: Vazio: Sem nenhuma informação dentro, ou seja `{}`, já consegui resolver manipulando o método `select` para retornar false caso não tenha sucesso em pegar o dado do `localStorage`. Mas não postei a resposta porque não é equivalente a pergunta. Seria fazer o equivalente á `if(!empty($array))` em php e `if(array.size() > 0)` em Java. Mas não achei nenhuma opção de verificar isso no Typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você não definiu propriedades adicionais para os seus objetos, você pode usar

```
...
if( Object.keys( item  ).length > 0 )
    all.push(item);
...
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-or-associative-array